# Application in Arguments principal

Tags: complex-analysis

Well I  found this problem and I believe it solved using argument principal's usage. We have a polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_nz^n$ where $c_{n-2}=0$ we have to prove that some $R>0$ big enough exists so  that $\displaystyle\bigg(\int_{|z|=R} z\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\ dz\bigg)^2 =$ $\displaystyle2πi\int_{|z|=R} z^2\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\ dz $.

What i have tried so far is

- using the principal as it is but i have to make an assumption using the fact that $c_{n-2}=0$ to go further and i don't know what this assumption is.
- I also tried not using the theorem and use $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{z-z_{i}}$ where $z_{i}$ are the roots of $p(z)$ but the $c_{n-2}=0$ will go to waste using this method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after all I think solved it what we need to is use vieta's formulas and   $p′(z)p(z)=∑^n_{i=0}\frac{1}{z−z_{i}}$ $\bigg(1\bigg)$. First we use $\bigg(1\bigg)$ and we have $∫_{|z|=R}z\frac{p′(z)}{p(z)} dz=$ $∫_{|z|=R}\sum^n_{i=0}\frac{z}{z−z_{i}}dz=$ $\sum^n_{i=0}∫_{|z|=R}\frac{z}{z−z_{i}}dz=$ $2πi\sum^n_{i=0}z_{i}$$\bigg(2\bigg)$ using this for every term we have
$\big(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}z_{i})\big)^2=$$\big(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}z_{i}\big)^2 + \big(\displaystyle\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}2z_{i}\big)$ but since $c_{n-2}=0$ we know from vietta's relations that $\big(\displaystyle\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}2z_{i}\big)$ = $c_{n-2}=0$.

**NOTES:**  u can prove $\bigg(2\bigg)$ using $Res(f,a)$ or analytically its easy thats why I pretermit it. This method is better than using Argument's principal cause u don't need to know the multiplicity of each root